# Deleting a specific character in a string from a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a problem in writing a query to sql. The problem is the following: there is a filled table with the FILE_NAME column, in this column it is necessary to delete the number 0 in a row in some elements. This 0 is always in the same place in the line. Below I attach a screenshot of the data, the yellow characters must be removed.

[image: problem]

Comment: I also try the following query: SELECT regexp_replace(FILE_NAME,'0(?=\d{3}_\d{3}$)','') as FILE_NAME_CORRECT, FILE_NAME FROM [TABLE]
and it returns the following exception: 
'regexp_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What is your criteria for removing zero from `18_0231_0121_001` and keeping zero in `18_0231_001_001`

Comment: 0 is always on 9 index in the string or it is not at all

Comment: second value (18_0231_001_001) has 0 in 9 index, and you wanna to keep it, please explain ?

Comment: the string must be in next format: 18_0000_000_000

Comment: I mean that I need to replace 0 in this index, only when there are 4 characters between second and third underscore
p.s. sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach via Using [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) and [LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions as next pattern:-

```
Update tableName
Set columnName = substring(columnName , 0, 9) +
                 substring(columnName , 10, len(columnName ))
Where substring(columnName , 9, 1) = '0' 
And len(columnName ) > 15
```

**Demo**

```
Create table #Temp (Col1 varchar(20))
insert into #Temp values ('18_0231_0121_001') -- Remove the 0 in index #9
insert into #Temp values ('18_0231_0121_12') -- keep the 0 in index #9
insert into #Temp values ('18_0231_2121_001') -- there is no 0 in index #9, so keep it as it is

select * from #Temp
```

**Result Before Update**

```
18_0231_0121_001
18_0231_0121_12
18_0231_2121_001
```

Use update as next

```
update #Temp 
set Col1 = substring(Col1, 0, 9) + substring(Col1, 10, len(Col1))
where substring(Col1, 9, 1) = '0' and len(Col1) > 15

select * from #Temp
```

**Result After Update**

```
18_0231_121_001
18_0231_0121_12
18_0231_2121_001
```

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

*0 is always on 9 index*

*replace 0 in this index, only when there are 4 characters between second and third underscore*

*the string must be in next format: 18_0000_000_000*

```
Update myTable
Set FILE_NAME = substring(FILE_NAME, 1, 8) +    -- first 8 characters
                substring(FILE_NAME, 10, 1000)  -- character 10 to end of string
where
   -- four characters with a zero at position 9 followed by of three characters and an underscroe
   Col1 like '_______\_0___\____' escape '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier with the `stuff()` function:

```
update tableName
    set columnName = stuff(columnName, 9, 1, '');
where substring(columnName , 9, 1) = '0' and len(columnName ) > 15;
```